# Adding Unique Objects into array in MongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm developing an API using node.js and mongoose which will accept and update data into MongoDB I have only push into unique records(object) into an array in DB.
I have schema like this

```js
const studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 name: String,
 reg_no: Number,
 year: Number,
 dept: String,
 mail: String,
 courses: [],
 workshops: [],
 events: [],
 semesters: [],
});
```

I need to add only unique objects to courses, workshops, events, semesters
where courses object will be like

```json
{
 "c_name": "crse",
 "organization": "OrgoCrse",
 "date": "12/12/01"
}
```

I have update only unique objects alone.

And not like this:

```json
[{
 "c_name": "crse",
 "organization": "OrgoCrse",
 "date": "12/12/01"
},
{
 "c_name": "crse2",
 "organization": "OrgoCrse2",
 "date": "12/11/01"
},
{
 "courseName": "crse",
 "organization": "OrgoCrse",
 "date": "12/12/01"
}]
```

Where two records of the same course is been added.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to store those events into their own collection. And then create a compound unique index on the three properties you mentioned.

Comment: Can U elaborate